# In react-native, why am I unable to define the width of my component?

Tags: react-native

With reference to the following Snack:

https://snack.expo.io/@deltanovember/shallow-scone

my Picker has an `<Icon />` that aren't properly aligned:

[image: The image of issue]

I've tried to fix this by fixing the width of the Picker to assign this style :

`style={{ width: 100 }}`

but the `<Icon />` still aren't aligning.

How can I get my `<Icon />` to align ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set width style to your picker like this :

```
style={{ width: '100%' }}
```

I try it in expo and it fixed :)

about the question mark it happened when you set the icon name wrong!

you can use this website to search in Icon names :

https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

**Extra**

you can get the screen width and use it where ever u want in your project like this :

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
const { width: WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window')
```